# Show unmatched records from different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables **test** and **test_new**. I want to show unmatched records from two rows of both tables.

table **test**:

```
id | name | age | class | emailid
---------------------------------------
1  | raj  | 24  | 8th   | raj@gmail.com
```

table **test_new**:

```
id | name | age | class | emailid
---------------------------------------
1  | raj  | 28  | 9th   | raj@gmail.com
```

When i am applying following code . Only counter of unmatched records is displayed, but I want to show unmatched values of rows also.

How can I display unmatched records?

**Ex:** In above tables values of age and class are different. I want to show only unmatched values means values of age and class of **test** table based on emailid.

**Code starts from here:**

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from test_new where emailid='raj@gmail.com'");
$matchvalues=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from test where emailid='raj@gmail.com'"));
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $counter=0;
    foreach($matchvalues as $value) {
        if(!in_array($value, $row)) {
            $counter++;
            print $counter."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show desired results.

Comment: your question is not clear, what is "UNMATCHED"?  do you want to compare records that have the same ID?  that have the same email?

Comment: I want to show unmatched values that have same email. Do not think about id. Value of age and class are unmatched. I want to compare row of both table that have same email and want to show unmatched value of test table only.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=mysql_query("select test.name as testname,test.age as testage,test.class as testclass,test_new.name as t1name,test_new.age as t1age,test_new.class as t1class from test JOIN test_new on test.emailid=test_new.emailid where test.emailid='raj@gmail.com'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if($row['testname']==$row['t1name'])
{
print $row['testname']."<br>";
}
if($row['testage']==$row['t1age'])
{
print $row['testage']."<br>";
}
if($row['testclass']==$row['t1class'])
{
print $row['testclass']."<br>";
}

}
```

Comment: It is useful. But if there are 50 columns in both table then your code will be very lenghty. Any short code????

Comment: i agree with you,but i have written above code as i got your table structure above.

Comment: I have 50 columns in both tables. I wrote only 5 columns, because 50 columns was too lenghty. So please tell me any short code. Its very urgent.

Answer (score 0):

```
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $counter=0;
        foreach($matchvalues as $value) {

        if($counter%2==1)   
{
            if($value!=$row[$counter]) {
            echo $value."<br>";
                       }
}
                $counter++; 
     }
    }
```

check it out this code

Comment: It repeats all the value of test table twice.

Comment: I replaced if($value!=$row[$counter]) from if(!in_array($value, $row)) then it works. Thank you very much.